# When are the two adjunction spaces $X_f$ and $X_g$ homotopy equivalent to each other?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $f,g: S^1\to S^1$ be continuous maps,
$$X_f=S^1\cup_fD^2=(S^1\cup D^2)/(x\sim f(x)\ | \ x\in S^1)\\
  X_g=S^1\cup_gD^2=(S^1\cup D^2)/(x\sim g(x)\ | \ x\in S^1)$$
Show that if $f$ is homotopic to $g$, then $X_f$ is homotopy equivalent to $X_g$.

This is an exercise of our Basic Topology course and it may be related to van Kampen theorem.

According to the theorem, by taking $U=(D^2)^\circ, V_f=(D^2-\{0\}\cup_f S^1), V_g=(D^2-\{0\}\cup_g S^1)$, we have $\pi_1(V_{f,g})\simeq\pi_1(S^1)\simeq \mathbb Z$ and $\pi_1(X_f)\simeq\mathbb Z/(\mathrm{Im}\ f_*)_N, \pi_1(X_g)\simeq\mathbb Z/(\mathrm{Im}\ g_*)_N.$ Since $f$ and $g$ induce the same homomorphism, the two fundamental groups are the same.

However, I have no idea about $X_f$ and $X_g$. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Being homotopy equivalent is a way stronger relation than that of having the same fundamental group. Forget about Van Kampen, and try to construct homotopy equivalences using the homotopy between $f$ and $g$. Maybe it would be a good idea to take a look at Hatcher's book, Chapter 0.

Comment: @Laz Thank you very much. I spent some time reading Hatcher's book. Its prop. 0.18 deals with a more general case. I really learnt a lot.

Comment: You are welcome! Hatcher is a great book.